# Can I manage to change the font of tmux status line, making it different from the terminal?

Tags: macos, tmux, iterm2

As the title says:

**Can I manage to change the font of tmux status line, making it different from the terminal?**

I'm using iTerm2 on macOs High Sierra, and I want to change the font of my tmux status line, making it different from the terminal's font. Is there any config I can use to make it?

Answer (score 0):

No, Tmux has no ability to use a different font than the parent terminal.

Comment: Not entirely true; with the correct terminal supporting escapes to switch fonts, `tmux` could change fonts the same way it does anything else: by writing the correct bytes to the terminal and letting *it* decide how to display those bytes. That said, iTerm2 is not such a terminal.

Comment: (I missed a level of indirection; you would tell `tmux` that it is running in an appropriate *terminal*, like `made-up-multifont` instead of `xterm`, and then you would need to use a terminal emulator that supports `made-up-multifont`.)

Comment: What's an example of a terminal that supports escape sequences to switch fonts? I read that Xterm can switch fonts, but it switches the font entirely, not for a string.

Comment: I'm not aware of any, but it could work the same way colors do: an escape sequence would notify the terminal that it should display the following text using a new font; that new font would be used until another set of font-change bytes is seen. The font choices themselves would be abstract, choosing `font-1`, `font-2`, or `font-3`, for example. It would be the job of the terminal emulator to map the abstract font specifiers to an actual font installed on the host system.

Answer (score 0):

To use the same font as your terminal uses in tmux you need to open tmux by
typing

tmux -u

don't type just

tmux

if you are typing this then tmux will use it's defalt boring font.

And we can't use a different font from the terminal's font.and tmux always uses the same font whatever be your terminal's font but if you want tmux to
use the same font as your terminal then you need to type the first command and not the second command.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself, you're saying it always uses the same font (your terminal's font) and then u say "if you want tmux to use the same font as your terminal". the `-u` option simply tells tmux that the terminal you are using supports UTF-8 Encoding.